# Change value of Dynamically created td on external event

Tags: jquery, json, datetimepicker

I have following code.

```
html += '<tr id="product_row_scheduled_'+key+'">';
html += '<td class="title">'+image_path+' '+product_row.title+'</td>';
html += '<td class="text-center" id="sch_product_posted_'+key+'"> '+product_row.user_set_time+'</td>';
html += '<td class="text-center"><a href="#" id="schedule_'+key+'" onClick="schedule_product(\''+key+'\',\''+product_row.title+'\',\''+product_row.user_set_time+'\')"> Schedule</a></td>';
html += '<td class="text-center"><a href="#" onClick="cancel_schedule(\''+key+'\')"> Cancel</a></td>';
html += '</tr>';
```

this is created using json data. now the function `schedule_product` changes the value of `sch_product_posted_'+key+'` using datetimepicker.

I have tried to use

```
$('#product_row_scheduled_'+key).on('change', '.product_posted_'+key+'',function(){
   console.log($('.product_posted_'+key+'').html());
});
```

but its not working. Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Why don't you use common class for event binding and then traversing DOM?

Comment: just use '.product_posted_'+key instead of '.product_posted_'+key+''

Comment: @Satpal ok its done thanks for your comment. I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `#` for `ids` like,

```
$('#product_row_scheduled_'+key).on('change', '#sch_product_posted_'+key,function(){
                                  // ----------^ # in place of .
    console.log($(this).html());// use this here
});
```

Using `class` instead of `id` would be simple like,

```
$(document).on('change', '.sch_product_posted',function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Add a class `sch_product_posted` to your `column`

**Updated** `change` will not work use [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMSubtreeModified) like,

```
$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified','.sch_product_posted', function(event){
    console.log('Html: '+$(this).html());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/cu9Ky/)**

Comment: still no luck. I have added class `sch_product_posted` to column and update jquery code but its not working.

Comment: How your column is `changing`? Note you wants to apply `change event` on column. You can check it is working or not by using a `click event` on your `column`.

Comment: I am changing value of the column by external event. on clicking `schedule_product` a modal appears from where user change change the value using bootstrap datetimepicker. on datetimepicker change event I want to update this field.